# Prevent site Flash player configuration info from showing up on Google

Tags: html, xml, seo, robots.txt, google-search

I tried asking this before, and I STILL haven't gotten a working answer to the issue, so I'm asking it again...

I have a site that's running WordPress.

The main page has an embedded Flash player and an embedded iframe, and for some reason, all the configuration info from the Flash player is showing up on Google for my site, and nothing else.

How can I have the main site information show up on Google, without having that Flash player config info show up?

And can I customize what shows up at all?

If there's some way to tag the info I don't want to show up, or tag the info I want to show up, I can probably do most ofthe edits myself, I just don't know where to start...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a couple of times [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html) without any acceptable answer.

I can't see inside the viewsource where the text(configuration) comes from, so I guess it's inside the .swf or some of the files used by the .swf

You may try to deny access for google to any(or specific) swf-files on serverside :

**Apache(.htaccess)**

```
BrowserMatchNoCase googlebot is_googlebot
<FilesMatch "\.swf">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=is_googlebot   
</FilesMatch>
```

(Then let google re-index your page for the changes to take affect, this may take some time )

Comment: Thanks for the info - it's a XML config file used by the SWF.
At least I now know why it's showing up...
Is there any nofollow tag I can add somewhere else so that the XML file isn't added?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, but you may try to set up a robots.txt and add `Disallow: /*.xml$`